# Should std::current_exception return non-null from catch block in a class's destructor

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, exception

My coworkers and I think we have found a bug in Visual C++ 2012 and 2013 but we aren't sure. Should the call to std::current_exception in the following code be expected to return a non-null exception_ptr? It seems to on most other compilers we've tried:

```
#include <exception>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <iostream>

class A
{
public:

    ~A()
    {
        try
        {
            throw std::runtime_error("oh no"); 
        }

        catch (std::exception &)
        {
            std::clog << (bool)std::current_exception() << std::endl;
        }
    }
};

void foo ()
{
    A aa;
    throw std::runtime_error("oh no");
}

int main(int argc, char **)
{
    try
    {
        foo();
    }
    catch(...)
    {
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When run under Visual C++ we get "0" (false, which means the exception_ptr returned is null). Other compilers, such as g++, print "1".

Comment: What version of MSVC are we talking about?  I haven't seen a case where MSVC was correct, and gcc and clang where *both* wrong, about something like this in years.  Note you are doing something strange (throwing an exception while an exception is being thrown).  Does this depend on the caught exception being ignored?  Is the (first) caught exception the correct value?  Does it change if we replace that `...` with `std::runtime_error const&` etc?

Comment: This is a known bug; it is still active and not yet fixed.  We do not currently plan to fix this for the next major release (Visual Studio 2015).

Comment: Thanks, James, I appreciate the confirmation.

Answer (score 4):

[cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/current_exception) says this about `std::current_exception`:

> If called during exception handling (typically, in a catch clause), captures the current exception object and creates an std::exception_ptr that holds either a copy or a reference to that exception object (it is implementation-defined if a copy is made).
>
> If the implementation of this function requires a call to new and the call fails, the returned pointer will hold a reference to an instance of std::bad_alloc
>
> If the implementation of this function requires to copy the captured exception object and its copy constructor throws an exception, the returned pointer will hold a reference to the exception thrown. If the copy constructor of the thrown exception object also throws, the returned pointer may hold a reference to an instance of std::bad_exception to break the endless loop.
>
> If the function is called when no exception is being handled, an empty std::exception_ptr is returned.

Throwing an exception unwind your stack which should call the destructor of your `A` class on your `aa` instance, in which you have a simple `try/throw/catch` bloc of code which catches the exception.

Of course it's not as authoritative as the standard, but it seems to me that g++/clang are right while visual is not (the other way around happens less often :p)

Comment: With cppreference gcc and clang on one side, and MSVC on the other, the smart money knows which side to bet on.  But a standards leaf reading might still be useful.

Answer (score 3):

As [confirmed by James McNellis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29652438/should-stdcurrent-exception-return-non-null-from-catch-block-in-a-classs-dest#comment47452691_29652438), this is definitely a bug. I had the great pleasure of discovering it today.

In your case, the workaround is to call `make_exception_ptr` instead of `current_exception` in your handler:

```
~A()
{
    try
    {
        throw std::runtime_error("oh no"); 
    }

    catch (std::exception & e)
    {
        std::clog << (bool)std::make_exception_ptr(e) << std::endl;
    }
}
```

But I think we are out of luck for `catch(...)` clauses and a fix is really needed.

**Edit1**: I reported this bug in "connect" a long time ago. It can now be found on [Developper Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/246364/msconnect-3127473-stdcurrent-exception-returns-an.html).

**Edit2**: The bug was fixed in VS2019 16.3.